# Consulta en MySQL no funciona en servidor pero si de forma local

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

tengo el siguiente problema.
Tengo 3 tablas (usuarios, fechas y pronosticos), estan relacionadas por medio de la tabla pronosticos. Lo que estuve haciendo de manera local fue consultarle a la BD "los pronosticos que hay disponibles pero que no me muestre los pronosticos ya hechos", ésto lo hice utilizando "except".
El problema aparece cuando subo la BD al servidor Clever Cloud y me dice que MySQL no soporta la sentencia "except" y ahora no me funciona la consulta que estaba realizando en Workbench de forma local. La consulta que funciona es asi:

```
SELECT 
    fechas.idfechas,
    fechas.num_fecha,
    fechas.local,
    fechas.visitante
    FROM fechas
    where fechas.resultado is null
    
except(
    
    SELECT
    fechas.idfechas, 
    fechas.num_fecha,
    fechas.local,
    fechas.visitante
    FROM fechas
    INNER JOIN pronosticos
    ON fk_idfechas = idfechas
    INNER JOIN usuarios
    ON fk_idusuarios = idusuarios
    
    and fechas.resultado is null);
```

Repito de forma local funciona perfectamente utilizando Woorkbench y el servidor utilizo Xampp.

Comment: Saludos. Intentaste verificar que la versión de tu MySQL y la del controlador de conexión de Xampp sean compatibles? Quizás estas usando un controlador obsoleto.

Comment: No probé eso, pero probé de realizar la consulta en el dashbord de Clever Cloud que utiliza phpMyAdmin y me da error de igual manera.

Comment: Podría ser por la forma en la que se realiza la conexión con tu servidor, no es lo mismo una conexión local que a tu servidor.  podrias agregar esa parte

Comment: Clever Cloud te brinda los datos de usuario y contraseña, con eso conectas a la BD. Y además sé que está funcionando la conexión a la BD porque me deja registrar usuarios y abrir sesión desde la web. Por eso estoy un 90% seguro que el error está en la consulta pero no se donde

Comment: Diría que localmente tienes mySQL 8 o superior, en el servidor, una versión anterior a la 8. La versión 8 introduce soporte para muchas expresiones del estándar que antes no estaban soportadas, CTE's, funciones de ventana y otras, entre ellas los operadores `intersect` y `except`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-nutshell.html

Comment: Controlé y, tanto localmente como en el servidor, es versión 8... No encuentro tampoco alguna sentencia similar que realice algo como except... Probé con "NOT" y tampoco